# Does Rails Remove Question Marks from Params Keys on a Post Request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have `questions` with a `text` attribute which is a string usually ending with a question mark.

Example:

`question.text = "Do you have any pets?"`

When submitting this text in a params hash, I noticed the `?` is removed from the params hash.

Example:

`Parameters: {"Do you have any pets"=>"Yes"}`

Is this automatically done by Rails? What's the best practice for handling this type of situation since it's affecting comparison checks I'm making upon save?

```
question.text = "Do you have any pets?"

params["Do you have any pets"] == "Yes" // true
params[question.text] == "Yes" // returns false
```

Comment: If I were you, I would not have random phrases as keys at all. Presumably, your questions are known beforehand. And so you can save them to the database and assign id to them. This way, your payload could look like this: `Parameters: {"158b5c6c-3ba6-454b-90b3-8db593c303bd" => "Yes"}`. Or if UUID look like an overkill, simple integer ids would work just as well.

Comment: At the very least, demote the phrase from a key to a value. `{"question" => "Do you have any pets?", "answer" => "Yes"}`